# Jean Dieudonné, problem 6, chapter III, §3

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Here is the beginning of this problem of *Linear algebra and elementary geometry*, §3.- Lines and hyperplanes :

---

> *Shear mappings (and dilatations)*. Let $E$ be a vector space over $\mathbb R$, $H$ a vector-hyperplane of $E$, $u $ a linear mapping of $E$ which leaves any element of $H$ invariant.
>
> 1. If $a$ is a vector of $E$ that does not belong to $H$, show that we can write $u(a)=\gamma a+t$, with $t\in H$ and that the scalar $\gamma$ is independent of the vector $a$ that does not belong to $H$.
>    In the following, it is assumed that $\boxed{\gamma =1}$
> 2. If $\gamma=1$ and if $g(x)=0$ is an equation of $H$, show that exists a unique $c\in H $ s.t. $u(x)=x+g(x)c$; $u$ is called *shear mapping* of hyperplane $H$ (show that $u$ is bijective).
> 3. If $u\neq 1_E$, show that $T:=D_{0c}$(Translator's Note: vector line passing through $c$) does not depend of the equation of $H$ chosen.
> 4. Show that the scalar 1 is the only eigenvalue of u(if $H\neq \{0\}$) and we have $E(1; u)=H$ if $u\neq 1_E$.
> 5. If $H\neq \{0\}$ and $u\neq 1_E$, show that the only vector lines $D$ such that $u(D)=D$ are the lines contained in $H$.

Here is what I've done :
[image]
1.- $u(a)$ can be written as $\gamma a +t$, with $\gamma\in \mathbb R$ and $t\in H$ because of the decomposition of $E$ into a direct sum $E=H\oplus \mathbb R a$.

Let $b=\xi a+t'$ another point that does not belong to $H$.$u(b)=\xi u(a)+t'=\xi \gamma a+\xi t+t'=\gamma (b-t')+\xi t+t'=\gamma b+T$, with $T\in H$.

---

In the following, it is assumed that $\gamma =1$, i.e. $u(a)=a+t$

---

2.- Let $x\in E, x=\xi a+h$. Then $h$ defined by $$\forall x\in E , h(x)=\xi$$is such that $h(x)=0$ is an equation of $H$. Then if $g(x)=0$ is another equation of $H, \exists \alpha\neq 0 $ s.t. $g=\alpha h$

$u(x)=\xi u(a)+h=\xi (a+t)+h=x+\xi t=x+g(x)\frac{t}{\alpha}$ .

Let $c:=\frac{t}{\alpha}\in H$. We have then $$\boxed{u(x)=x+g(x)c}\color{red}{(*)}$$

3.- If $h(x)=\beta \xi=0$ is another equation of $H$, it is easy to associate the same line$$T:=D_{0c}$$

4.- According to $\color{red}{(*)}$, $u(x)=x\iff g(x)=0\iff x\in H$

So $1$ is an eigenvalue and $E(1;u)=H$

---

All that remains is to complete 4 and answer 5. But first of all, I'd like someone to check my assertions if you want to

Comment: I don't get what is $t$

Comment: Okay, I'll clarify in the post

Comment: I don’t understand the premise. Why can $u$ not be a reflection across $H$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin : it is possible in question 1) where we also get the dilations, but from question 2), we fix $\gamma=1$ and so $\gamma \neq -1$(The Case of Reflections). I modified the post with "(*and dilations*)".

Comment: In fact, problem 6 is so extensive that I had to make choices to get a post of a reasonable size.

Comment: You might find my [notes](https://github.com/blargoner/math-geometry-dieudonne/blob/master/exercises.pdf) helpful.

Comment: @blargoner : yes, great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the equation $u(x) = x+g(x)c$, we see that there can be no further eigenvectors. Suppose $u(x)=\lambda x$ for some scalar $\lambda$. Then $(\lambda-1)x = g(x)c$. Either $\lambda=1$ and $g(x)=0$ (we cannot have $c=0$ since $u\ne 1_E$) or $x = \frac{g(x)}{\lambda-1} c$, in which case $x\in H$ and $g(x)=0$, so $x=0$.

The language "vector hyperplane" and "vector line" is not standard in mathematical English. I assume these are to refer to subspaces as opposed to *affine* subspaces. A one-dimensional subspace invariant under $u$ must be an eigenspace, hence must be a subspace of $H$.

What about an affine line? Consider a line of the form $x=x_0+\mu v$, with $\mu\in\Bbb R$ and $x_0$ and $v$ fixed. Then if the line is $u$-invariant, for each $\mu$ we have $u(x_0+\mu v) = x_0+\mu v + g(x_0+\mu v)c = x_0 + \tau v$ for some $\tau\in\Bbb R$. From this we conclude that $v$ is a scalar multiple of $c$, and so the line is parallel to $H$. Indeed, lines parallel to $c$ are $u$-invariant.

Comment: Yes, "vector hyperplane" is to refer to a subspace as opposed to "affine hyperplane". In the text of Dieudonné, "hyperplan affine" and "hyperplan vectoriel". Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I realized that I hadn't proved that u is bijective but I found by considering $v(x)=x-g(x)c$